# Testing iOS app going into foreground

Tags: ios

I have a strange behavior where my app enters a black screen state when coming back into foreground from the ipod being put on 'sleep' (pressing the 'hold' button). Unfortunately, I am unable to set breakpoints because every time the app goes into the background while the debugger is attached, it crashes on the main loop. This behavior also occurs when I press home, and then navigate back to the app. Should I be able to set breakpoints that trigger even when the app is in the background? What is the strategy for testing these app lifecycle changes?

Comment: Yes your breakpoints should work when the app comes back to foreground, assuming that it hasn't been terminated while at background of course. Where do you set the breakpoints ? Try the earliest of your code that is going to execute when the app comes to foreground.

Comment: Thanks for the help! What happened was the SDK I am using (oovoo video chat) wasn't properly being put into the background, and so the app was actually crashing, like you say, when it came into the foreground. After looking at the sample code, I determined that I am supposed to inform the Oovoo SDK of the current application lifecycle by calling certain methods in my appdelegate. Oovoo didn't document this requirement. Thanks a bunch!